# PlayOnLinux Equivalent for windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu-12.04

Like the PlayOnLinux do we have a similar application in windows that allows us to run a Ubuntu application on Windows OS. Or is there any simulator to run the ubuntu terminal in Windows(for learning purpose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## you can't

Unfortunately there is no such tools like playonlinux(wine frontend) for simulating linux apps in windows, So you should use virtual machine craigwin